# Materiel.io expanding bottom sheet

Tags: android

I'm new in android and I like to make bottom sheet like the one in the photo with java android. I can't find working sample or tuorial showing haw doing this in java. can anyone help me please.[image]

Comment: Please try to share your tried approach, below is the example of bottom sheet you can follow.
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-sheet/

Comment: thanks for response, I tried this tutorial for classic bottom sheet. But I need corners bottoms sheets likes on the top. i can not find titurials about its.